# Count the number of rows that meet any criteria in some columns (OR-like operation)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

Say we have the following table:

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  0  |  T  |  0  |  T  | (B[0] == T OR D[0] == T)
|  1  |  T  |  1  |  T  | (B[1] == T OR C[1] > 0 OR D[1] == T)
|  2  |  T  |  0  |  F  | (B[2] == T)
|  3  |  F  |  0  |  F  | (doesn't meet any criteria)
|  4  |  F  |  2  |  F  | (C[4] > 0)
|  5  |  F  | -1  |  F  | (doesn't meet any criteria)
```

I hope to do something like `COUNTORS(B:B, true, C:C, ">0", D:D, true)` that returns `4`.

That is, for a single row, if any value in column B, C, D meets the criteria, then we should count it (+=1).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B = TRUE; 1; 0)+
                  IF(C:C > 0;    1; 0)+
                  IF(D:D = TRUE; 1; 0)))
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B:B=TRUE)*(C:C>0)*(D:D=TRUE), 1, 0)))
```

for `OR` logic use:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B:B=TRUE)+(C:C>0)+(D:D=TRUE), 1, 0)))
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve what I want. I hope to output a single value that is equal to `4`.

Comment: This won't return the correct value `4`. Instead, it'll return `7` because there're 5 values == T and 2 values > 0.

Comment: For example, if there're 3 values satisfy the criteria in a row, that row should still contribute `1` instead of `3`.

Comment: The problem with your last update is that `(B:B=TRUE)*(C:C>0)*(D:D=TRUE)` will act as an `AND` statement, but the user wants to implement it as an `OR` I posted a solution that does work but I'm sure that you can come up with something much neater having your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

@player0 answer didn't work for me, so I adapted to make something that I could use, although my answer is much uglier.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B:B=TRUE)+(C:C>0)+(D:D=TRUE) > 1, 1, (B:B=TRUE)+(C:C>0)+(D:D=TRUE) )))
```

The most obvious solution was to use `OR` inside an `IF` statement, but for some reason it didn't play well with `ARRAYFORMULA` instead I directly summed all the conditions and set the value to 1 in case it was higher to not count multiple columns for the same row.

[image: Final result]